# What is the value of property in ios

Tags: multithreading, atomic, nonatomic

In Atomic we all know one thread is access one object at a time. if we have 3 thread want to access one object then first come first serve method apply to thread ... but in non atomic all thread is simultaneously access the oject and produce the unpredictable result ..

Now i want to know that result.

ex.

```
suppose @property (non atomic) NsString *name;
@synethesize name;

[self setname : @"A"]
[self setname : @"B"]
[self setname : @"B"]
```

Now what is the result in case of non atomic ..

Thanks inadvance

Comment: I don’t think your question is clear enough that anybody will be able to give you a useful answer.

Comment: actually i need to know the answer while we use nonatomic property..